# Why does Limit not compute simple limits involving integer parts?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-9

I asked Mathematica to compute for me the following limit:

`Limit[IntegerPart[M a]/M, M -> Infinity]`

Whatever `a` is, the limit should come out as `a`. Indeed, this is the result whenever I plug in any explicit value of `a`. Unfortunately, as stated above, the limit does not compute (Mathematica returns exactly the same formula). I tried simplifying the expression with some extra assumptions on `a` (thinking that maybe Mathematica isn't sure that `a` is a real):

`FullSimplify[Limit[IntegerPart[M a]/M,M->\[Infinity]], Assumptions-> a > 1]`

but this does not help. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I get `ConditionalExpression[a, a > 0]` in MMA 11.3.

Comment: Hm... I'm in Mathematica 9.0.

Comment: Limits in *Mma* have come a long way since V9.0....especially on functions that are not analytic/meromorphic.